# How to know the time that a user has been somewhere?

Tags: android, google-play-services, locationmanager

I am using Android `LocationManager` to check if a user is around a Location that I have defined.

I am using `addProximityAlert` method so that I receive an intent when the user is where I expect.

However, what I would like to do is to know if a user is in the given place for a period of time because if a user is crossing through the location I am checking, I may also receive the intent.

My first approach is that after some time (some minutes) I can check it again. Is there a better approach? Is there any way to receive the intent only after some time has passed?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, you could use an `if` statements to store the elapsed time of the user being in a certain distance.
 You could use `System.currentTimeMillis()` to get the current time and then subtract the original start time from it, to give you the elapsed time. Here is something you could do:

```
long startTime = 0;
long elapsedTime;
// Set up LocationManager here
Location targetPlace;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    // Checks to see if the user was already there when they opened the activity
    if(location.distanceTo(targetPlace) == 5) {
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
    targetPlace = new Location(provider);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if(startTime != 0) {
        // Check to see if the user is in a given place
        if (location.distanceTo(targetPlace) == 5) {
            elapsedTime = (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000; // Time in seconds
        } else {
            // User is not near that location
        }
    } else {
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}
```

Change '5' in the `if` statement to whatever you want the radius to be. Hope this helps!

Comment: I get the idea but this is not what I want and it is not using proximity alert. What your code is doing is get the time between onCreate and locationChanged. What I want is, not in an activity but in background, to be advised only when the user has been in the location for X minutes.